# PHP - Storing paragraph in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, string, longtext

I might sound silly with simple questions . i am newbie exploring PHP , kindly help me mates.

I want to store paragraph in MySQL table .

My PHP code was

> $text="This was the first book or more to say a novel, I read in my
>   life. when I read other reviews about this book and also enquired with
>   my friends, they were not very happy about this book but when I read
>   this book I felt the same language which we are used to from Chetan's
>   books, yes it is nowhere near to his works like Five Point someone or
>   2 States but it isn t bad either, the way he gives background to each
>   character and ties up all the loose ends together is what I like in
>   this book as well, it also touches a few sensitive aspects of Gujarat
>   but also explains how they impact business and people. you will be
>   amazed to know i Completed it in 7 days. I couldn t control my
>   excitement of what will happen next after reading each chapter. Some
>   good points to understand especially Indian Politics and the most its
>   dark side political of religion and caste. Well of all I like trios
>   book What can I say more read it and have some time of excitement of
>   what.Surely not only sex. much about emotions. A good piece by Chetan
>   Bhagat. --Vicky on 27 May 2015";

it's not storing

But, suppose if i try the following it works

```
$text="test";
```

so , i think longtext might be the issue . However in table the field type is LongText only

Kindly help me please

Comment: Escape the paragraph before storing.

Comment: Escape the string before trying to insert it. You've got apostrophes in the string which will screw up your MYSQL query.

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in your query to escape the text.

Comment: You need to escape string before storing into database, if i not wrong, the double dash makes the last part of sql query commented and  the ' sign part error and cause query error.  always `echo mysql_error()` to get know mysql's errors.

Comment: The word Chetan's could be replaced with `Chetan\'s` or `Chetan&#39;s`.  But as @GeoffAtkins mentioned, it is best to use generally escape the string.

Comment: @Sablefoste That saved me a lot mate . i changed to "Chetan\'s"  and it worked !!! . if you post this as answer i will make it worked choice so that some newbie's will understand mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

> Chetan's

to

> Chetan\'s

solved the issue

thanks to @Sablefoste as this is his suggestion .

Regarding `mysqli_real_escape_string()` i will try escaping the string as others advised.